# how to convert line-delimited txt file into a spreadsheet file as tsv or xls

Tags: bash, csv

I have a huge amount of phone numbers (for example), one for each line in `.txt` file.
202898990
909090090
909090900
...

I want to put each number in a a cell (phone numbers in the same column). I think I have first to convert it to `.csv`. But don't know how to do it.

Thanks a lot

Comment: This *is* a valid single-column CSV file exactly as it is. Also, this question may be better on superuser (since it's not _really_ a programming question, but an "how do I accomplish this task?" question, with shell programming as an assumed answer).

Comment: Just to add to Charles' comment, you can rename your file `whatever.csv`. The extension doesn't make it a `csv` file, but it will identify a properly formatted CSV file as such.

Answer (score 2):

Since your file already *is* a valid CVS file, just change the file's extension to "csv" and open in your favorite spreadsheet. It should be imported the way you want.